# Cache miss issue

Tags: javascript, typo3

When I submit form using post method search result will appear.After I select a particular result it will go to  detail page. When I use browser back button then following issue will occur.[Cache miss issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqx1m.png)

Do anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form using the post method is used to send data to the server.

Given the data sent to the server, the server could answer one thing or another. Even when you resend the same data to the server, it could answer differently every time (because you already submitted the data once).

When you navigate back in your browser history, your browser tells you that it cannot show you the same page because the data was already sent once. And if you still want to see this page, you should re-submit the form.

However, because the server can show you something different even if you send the same data, this cannot be trusted!

Because this is a frequent problem, here is the commonly accepted solution:

1/ Submit your form using the post method to a particular url (e.g: /something/submit)

2/ In the server, send the data to a database, then redirect to a GET url (e.g: /something-else)

3/ In the server, when requesting the /something-else page, use the database to send back the previously sent data.

Comment: A better solution would be to use GET instead of POST, but if that's not an option (because there's too much information) you should use session data instead of the database unless you want to save it indefinitely. Session data is cleaned automatically.

Comment: It depends on what he's trying to achieve. But if the data doesn't need to be saved then a GET could be the solution indeed.

Comment: Thank you for helping to find solution.But I require POST method and there is no need to save data in database.